# How does the register form in the user module load ImageWidget?

Tags: 8, forms

[image]
I want to use the user picture widget on the user register form to capture an image. So for my custom entity form I'm using the managed_file as such 
**modules/custom_module/src/CustomEntityForm.php**

```
public function form(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
      $form['deal']['image'] = array(
          '#type' => 'managed_file',
...
```

the above code does not add the widget as seen on the register form, i.e  It does not have the preview functionality widget which I think it comes from the image widget.

This line seems to be responsible for the output of the widget on the register form
**ContentEntityForm.php** Line 122

```
public function form(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
$this->getFormDisplay($form_state)->buildForm($this->entity, $form, $form_state);
```

after buildForm() the $form array has a new inner array keyed 'user_picture'. This is var_dump

```
 'user_picture' => 
    array (size=7)
      '#type' => string 'container' (length=9)
      '#parents' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string 'user_picture_wrapper' (length=20)
      '#attributes' => 
        array (size=1)
          'class' => 
            array (size=3)
              ...
      'widget' => 
        array (size=6)
          0 => 
            array (size=28)
              ...
          '#after_build' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          '#field_name' => string 'user_picture' (length=12)
          '#field_parents' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          '#parents' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          '#tree' => boolean true
      '#access' => boolean true
      '#weight' => int -1
      '#cache' =>
```

this is way up in the core code. how does the user module configure all this to use imageWidget?  Do I need to configure something for EntityFormDsiplay?

Comment: It's a field, so add it in `baseFieldConditions` of your entity class, or add it to your entity module's install config (like the user module itself does with user_picture). Then it will automatically be available on your entity form

Comment: @Clive user_picture is a field?? where is baseFieldConditions?  I don't see any thing related to user_picture  in user/config/install

Comment: My bad, it's actually the Standard installation profile which creates it (/core/profiles/standard/config/install/field.storage.user.user_picture.yml and /core/profiles/standard/config/install/field.field.user.user.user_picture.yml). But yeah, it's a field